# Авторедирект с ссылок которых нет в urlpatterns

Tags: python, django, redirect

У меня на сайте есть только две страницы : ***[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)*** и ***[www.example.com/delete](http://www.example.com/delete)***.
Соответственно urlpatterns выглядит так:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', MainView.as_view()),
path('delete/<int:number>', DeleteView.as_view())]
```

Если пользователь вводит в адресную строку ***[www.example.com/about](http://www.example.com/about)*** - он получает ошибку 404.
Что нужно сделать что-бы при вводе любой ссылки которой нет в urlpatterns срабатывал redirect на ***[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)***?

Comment: Можете в конце `urls.py` указать `url(r'.+', `redirect_view,)`, redirect_view напишите сами или если найдете стандартную..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый просто вариант это переопределить стандартное поведение `handler404`

во views

```
def bad_request(request, *args):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main'))
```

в urls приложения я бы добавил `name`

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', MainView.as_view(),name='main'),
path('delete/<int:number>', DeleteView.as_view())]
```

в urls проекта

```
from django.conf.urls import handler404
handler500 = 'app_name.views.bad_request'
handler404 = 'app_name.views.bad_request'
```

При этом надо будет поставить `DEBUG=False`

Comment: Не совсем понимаю что такое и для чего здесь reverse('main')?

Comment: @SuddenDumb revers функция в django в который указывается `name` для генерации url адреса . Вы конечно можете просто указать `HttpResponseRedirect('/')`

Comment: Теперь вместо ошибки Not Found получаю Server Error (500)

Comment: @SuddenDumb необходимо добавить еще `handler500 = 'app_name.views.bad_request'`